# Airborne GET from test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rest-client, rails-api, airborne

Using Airborne, how can I use GET to return values from test environment?

For example, I have the following test:

```
it 'should foo the bar' do
  product = FactoryGirl.create(:product)
  get "/v1/products"
  pp product
  pp body
  expect_status 200
end
```

The output of `product` is:

```
#<Product:0x007f9dfe601078
 id: 847,
 ref: "038-71-8140174268593",
 name: "Adipisci Sqryujdcoefpthnzbvagwlxikm",
 description:
  "Lorem ipsum...",
 created_at: Tue, 01 Nov 2016 15:48:25 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Tue, 01 Nov 2016 15:48:25 UTC +00:00>
```

But the output of body is:

```
"{\"data\":[]}"
```

I have rails server running test environment with `rails s -e test`

If I run rails server with development environment, the `body` returns all products from dev environment with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I was running the test with `RSpec.describe ProductResource, type: :resource do` instead of `RSpec.describe 'Products', type: :request do`.